# HEROKU scaffold.css isn't precompiled

Tags: css, heroku, scaffold

I almost run my first ROR app on HEROKU but I've got problem with css. It's sth wrong with precompilation...

LOGS:

> 2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 app[web.1]: 2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00
>   app[web.1]: 2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for
>   77.236.11.34 at 2011-10-31 12:23:15 -0700 2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StoreController#index as HTML
>   2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered store/index.html.erb
>   within layouts/application (0.1ms) 2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00
>   app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms
>   2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 app[web.1]: 2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00
>   app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (scaffold.css isn't
>   precompiled): 2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 app[web.1]: 2: 
>   2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 app[web.1]: 3: 
>   2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 app[web.1]: 4: Animal Store
>   2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 app[web.1]: 5: <%= stylesheet_link_tag
>   "scaffold" %> 2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 app[web.1]: 6: <%=
>   stylesheet_link_tag "depot", :media => "all" %>
>   2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 app[web.1]: 7: <%= javascript_include_tag
>   :defaults %> 2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 app[web.1]: 8: <%=
>   csrf_meta_tag %> 2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in
>   `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1702959470674454677_27491740'
>   2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 app[web.1]: 2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00
>   app[web.1]: 2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
>   2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 heroku[router]: GET
>   eerie-meadow-9207.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=16ms
>   status=500 bytes=728 2011-10-31T19:23:15+00:00 heroku[nginx]:
>   77.236.11.34 - - [31/Oct/2011:12:23:15 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl-PL; rv:1.9.2.23)
>   Gecko/20110921 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.23"
>   eerie-meadow-9207.heroku.com

any ideas?

Comment: can you give use more details? Are you using Rails 3.1? Is this using SASS?

Comment: I've changed 'config.assets.enabled = false' in config/application.rb and it works but still doesn't use my .css files.. RAILS 3.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using the Cedar stack not Bamboo - from your snippet I can see

```
eerie-meadow-9207.heroku.com
```

it should be .herokuapp.com if you're on the Cedar stack which Rails 3.1 works on out of the box.

Comment: frankly, I have no idea how can I change it...when I run command heroku stack I get   aspen-mri-1.8.6
* bamboo-mri-1.9.2
  bamboo-ree-1.8.7
  cedar (beta) when I change config.assets.enabled = false' in config/application.rb it worked but It still doesn't use my .css file

Comment: `heroku stack` shows which stack your application is running on by the *. You will need to create a new app on Cedar `heroku create --stack cedar` and push your application to that one.

Comment: There's no way to change the stack up to Cedar. In your project `git remote rm heroku` then `heroku create --stack cedar` then `git push heroku master` and you should be fine.